# Problems with Setting Parent for an Object

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I try to set the parent for an instantiated object, I get this error:

```
Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a prefab is disabled to prevent data corruption.
UnityEngine.Transform:SetParent(Transform)
```

I've searched Google for the same error and it seems not to be the problem in my case.

The code:

```
[SerializeField] GameObject scoreboardItem;
[SerializeField] Transform playerList;

GameObject itemGO = (GameObject) Instantiate(scoreboardItem);
itemGO.transform.SetParent(playerList);
```

Any solutions for solving the problem?

Comment: Make sure the playerList Transform you drag drop to the inspector comes from your `Hierarchy` panel and not your `Project` panel.

Comment: That doesn't work since I then breaks the prefab if I do so. I've also tried to find the playerList by GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag().transform but same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I needed to do the following inside same method and not in the start method:

```
GameObject scoreList = GameObject.FindWithTag("ScoreboardContent");
```

Answer (score 0):

Playerlist must be an object reference. But it is not, it is just data.